# SPSS loop to create copy of variable list while renaming?

Tags: spss

So I have a pattern list of variables I need to create and equal amount of dummy variables while changing the numerical variable name by an increment.

list = [100_1,100_2,100_3....100_22, 210_1,210_2.....]

I need to be able to match the length of each variable list and create additional dummy variables. So for example for the 100 pattern I need to create 101_1, 101_2...102_1, 102_2...and so on for each variable.

Each variable pattern has a different length, but none exceeding 20 or so. I'm assuming it's much easier to do this in a python block, but not really sure where to start.

Comment: Normally there will be more than one dummy variable for any given variable -- i.e. if Q100_1 can have values (1, 2, 3), then there will be three dummies Q100_1_1, Q100_1_2, and Q100_1_3.  So, what do these variables contain that there'd be exactly one dummy per variable?

Comment: Also, is the "increment variable number by one" thing a hard requirement, or can appending a number (as in the convention used above) work?